# cuda_dnn error with Tensorflow in Windows: "could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED"

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I want to perform some calculation with TensorFlow, Keras and Nvidia GeForce GPU on Windows. I installed the required software and it worked fine (TensorFlow, tensorflow-gpu, Keras, Nvidia driver, CUDA v9.2, CUDA DNN 9.0). I managed to perform some calculations.

Now, suddenly something went wrong since TensorFlow crashes Python when executing `model.fit`. The log messages are the following:

```
2018-06-14 06:43:44.339292: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:
0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1423 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2018-06-14 06:43:45.231652: **E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:455] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED**
2018-06-14 06:43:45.231904: E T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:459] error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows 
2018-06-14 06:43:45.232704: F T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:713] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
[I 06:44:05.636 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel cc7fe8f9-2c33-4e3d-9af6-8ddb6a12c0bb restarted
```

I tried to limit the `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` from the Python code, but it didn't help.

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True, per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.1)
s = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

I simply can't find the solution for Windows platform to this problem. I even tried to delete the Nvidia local cache files, but it didn't help either...

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of digging, I issued two commands at Anaconda prompt:

***pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu***

Which solved probably some local inconsistency and now everything works again.